# iPad/iPhone Development Question

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4

I am new to xCode and have a pretty basic question. I started by creating a new Windows Based Application project.  I have a MainWindow.xib that has a UIViewController which uses a nib entitled MyViewController.  Now in MyViewController I have some controls, but when one of the controls is clicked, I want to switch to a NavigationController.

So, the question is, can I do this all using one MainWindow.nib and then add all the views there... such as my UIViewController, and then my UINavigationController all pointing to separate nib files?  Or, do I need multiple MainWindow.xib files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways. You can make a UINaviationController programatically or load it from another XIB.

In either case you might have to present them modally.

If you are new to it, why don't you rethink the design of the app and use the Navigation Controller based template for your app?